# How to choose the number of components PCA scikitliear

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, decomposition

I'm trying to decompse my columns using PCA .

I'm finding some difficulties about how to choose my
n_components of the function PCA using scikit learn in python. 
I did this

```
sc = StandardScaler()
Z = sc.fit_transform(X)
pca = PCA(n_components = 5')
```

Can you explain me please .

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is not a general problem solving site. Please explain what you have already tried and provide the code of your attempt. We can then discuss any issues

Comment: Post edited .. thank you

Comment: Please note that your code is incorrect. `PCA(svd_solver='full, n_components = 5')` is a syntactic error

Comment: yes im sorry !! i just edited . My problem is how to know n_components  = which number to decompose on ..Thank youu so much

Comment: This really depends on your application. Why do you run PCA? How much of the variance in your input do you want to retain?

Comment: i don't know how. Im just using PCA to reduce the number of columns, i have initially 70 variables .. and im asked to do PCA .. so i i centred an reduced my initial data and now im trying to fix n_components correctly.. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 13):

There is no answer that will tell you with probability 1 what is correct number of components. It is application specific.

However there is a following heuristic that you can use.
You plot explained variance ratio and choose a number of components that "capture" at least 95% of the variance.
In following example the number of components that capture around 95% of the variance is around 30.

```
pca = PCA().fit(digits.data)
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean 30?